# Emotion analysis using AlchemyAPI in python

Tags: python, alchemyapi, emotion

I want to use the Python-SDK for Emotion Analysis using the `AlchemyAPI`.

```
from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI    
alchemyapi = AlchemyAPI()
demo_text = 'I am happy'
alchemyapi.emotion('text', demo_text)
```

gives this error:

```
AttributeError: AlchemyAPI instance has no attribute 'emotion'
```

How do I make an API call to detect emotions as mentioned [here](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/alchemylanguage/emotion-analysis)?

[image: A screenshot of the alchemyapi demo predicting emotions]

Answer (score 2):

Please follow all the steps above:

1. **Get Your Free [API Key](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/register/)** - AlchemyAPI requires an API Key to access their text analysis functions.
2. **Clone Python SDK from [GitHub](https://github.com/alchemyapi/alchemyapi_python)** - To make using AlchemyAPI easier, they've created a software development kit, or `SDK` for short.

**Hint:**

```
mkdir -p ~/src/test
cd ~/src/test
git clone https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python.git
cd alchemyapi_python/
```

**3. Configure the Python SDK to use your API Key** - all you need to do is configure it to use your API key:

```
python alchemyapi.py YOUR_API_KEY
```

**4. Run a simple Example:**

```
python example.py
```

At this point you should get lots of output in the terminal window as each function is called and the output is parsed.

Now, to be able to use `AlchemyAPI` functionality just copy and paste the `alchemyapi.py` file into your project, and in the file that will handle the text analysis include the following lines:

```
from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
alchemyapi = AlchemyAPI()
```

Now you can use the alchemyapi object to access any of the text analysis functions:

```
myText = "I'm excited to get started with AlchemyAPI!"
response = alchemyapi.sentiment("text", myText)
print "Sentiment: ", response["docSentiment"]["type"]
```

*Disclaimer*: make sure that you follow all these steps in order to be able to access the API.

Comment: I have done these steps. What I want is `emotions`. I want my sentence to be classified into `joy, sadness, fear, anger, disgust` like how it is done [here](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage). [This](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/alchemylanguage/emotion-analysis) is a page on what exactly I want to do.